# What does exit 99 means?

Tags: shell, exit

I want to know what is exit 99 and why would one use it and what are the significance uses of it.

For example, I'm using `exit 99`.

Comment: Pretty much similar answer to [SO: "Why return a negative errno? (e.g. return -EIO)"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1848900/202229)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no significance to exiting with code 99, other than there is perhaps in the context of a specific program.

Either way, `exit` exits the shell with a certain exit code, in this case, 99. You can find more information in `help exit`:

```
exit: exit [n]
    Exit the shell.

    Exits the shell with a status of N.  If N is omitted, the exit status
    is that of the last command executed.
```

Comment: If you want to do something specific with a return code like that in bash, use the `$?` to get to it.

Comment: Not quite - 99 is not zero, and so indicates that the program failed for some reason.

Comment: @psusi There are plenty of non-zero exit codes in applications that are not to do with failure, but indicate other execution conditions (many programs use it to indicate falsiness or non-optimal execution rather than failure, for example). To assert that a certain exit status *must* indicate failure without knowing the program is simply not true. I won't speculate on the meaning of "99" in some unknown program.

Comment: The shell, and most other tools, including make, treat any non zero exit value as an error.

Comment: @psusi They have no way of knowing what exit code 99 means unless you give it actionable meaning by programming in a certain way -- you'll find plenty of make scripts with commands returning truthiness followed by `|| true`. The shell and/or make is not something that can discern the inherent meaning of exit statuses, and it so happens that usually this is what is desirable (but being frequently true is not enough for me to desire to speculate that it is true for whatever use case the original question entails).

Comment: They know it means failure because that is the convention for exit status: anything other than zero means something went wrong.  The specifics of what what went wrong ( and this may be very minor and something you may want to ignore if you know the specifics ) are up to the application.

Comment: Except for these only indicate failure in isolation, not in larger context of checking for truthiness. Either way, I refuse to speculate on the meaning of some exit code when the application is not defined.

Comment: @psusi the exit code doesn't fail anything - the test for a 0 exit code fails when you test it. If you `[ $? -eq 99 ]` a 99 exit code will pass.

Comment: @mikeserv, properly written scripts use `set -e` to enable error checking so you don't have to test every exit status yourself.  Any program you call that returns non zero will be treated as an error and cause the script to abort.  `make` will also automatically stop the build and report an error if it calls something that returns non zero, again, without you needing to explicitly test the value.  In fact, your `[ $? -eq 99 ]` returns 0 for success and 1 for failure.

Comment: @psusi I also do not agree with that statement for a couple of reasons. In the first place, properly written scripts are programs and so i dont agree there is such a thing . But if there were, it would not rely on a shell option to handle exceptions and tests would be explicit in one way or another. And yes, as you say, the convention is to return zero, but properly written scripts would also not rely on convention. Still, you have a point - i dont say we should stray from convention - that would be unnecessarily difficult - only that we shouldnt rely on it.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to @Chris Down, there is some return code that reserved for the shell, they have special meaning:

```
RETVAL   Meaning

1        General errors
2        Misusage
127      Command not found
```

You can refer to [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) for more details.

Comment: @MrLister: Yeap, my mistypo, fixed!

Comment: there is still a `s` missing in there ("Misuage"?)

Answer (score 2):

Normally, if you finish your script at some point with:

```
exit 0
```

The shell will get a 0 as the **return code**. This zero means **everything was OK**.

However, if your program has found some error condition, you should exit with a non-zero return code, to inform the shell that something has gone wrong. If you don't want to be more specific, you can simply use 1.

```
exit 1
```

You can however, inform the shell of particular type of failures by using other numbers. For example, `bash` itself returns a 127 for *program not found*. So if you document the behaviour of your script, you can do something useful after running it by checking the value of the special variable `$?`, which holds the return code of the last executed program.

I looked into this a while ago and found that, for example, FreeBDS had some very useful conventions with regards to exit codes, documented in [`man 3 sysexits`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%204.3-RELEASE&format=html)

Comment: "The shell will get a 0 as the return code" wrong, `exit` without parameters exits with the status code of the last command run. (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/exit.html)

Comment: Thank you, long standing misconception of mine, will fix the answer.

Comment: Great, downvote removed :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very long-standing convention (in Unix) for return-status ranges:

- **0 means success**
- **positive numbers mean minor problems, but essentially the task completed**
- **negative numbers mean critical error** (e.g. disk-full, file-not-found)

Exactly what those individual positive and negative numbers mean is up to the programmer. Sometimes you can choose them for compatibility with other similar programs (e.g. Gnu tools).
@Gnouc lists some.

No, I'm not aware of any special significance to exit code 99, never seen it used.
Maybe it means *'Not enough beer'*

See:

- answer to [SO: "Why return a negative errno? (e.g. return -EIO)"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848900/202229)
  also
- [show list of standard Unix error codes culled from errno.h](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=274896), although these are positive.

Comment: I never heard of that Unix convention.  And your two references do not support your assertion about that convention.

Comment: The first reference does. There are 1.67m google hits on *unix return status positive negative numbers*.

Comment: There are a small number of negative return values specified in POSIX.1 but these are for programming APIs

Answer (score 0):

Some programmers will supply a lot of different errorcodes starting with 1.
New versions might introduce new specific errorcodes, so which code should be used for
"all other errors / unspecified error" ?
The exit codes will be truncated at 255, so I would choose 99 as an "other error".